# CSS image blur after a few seconds without hover

Tags: css, filter, blur

Is it even possible to start with a non-blurred image and have it blur after a few seconds using only css? If so, how would I go about making this work??

Answer (score 0):

You can use a transition with CSS and add a transition delay.

More about [transition](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp).
More about [CSS Blur](http://css-plus.com/2012/03/gaussian-blur/).

Comment: It would be appropriate that you also add a code sample that illustrates the way to accomplish the desired. Just pasteing links that might go off after some time adds no value to your answer.

Comment: I am familiar with both, however my question is can it be done WITHOUT hovering - and if so, HOW??

Comment: I guess that's it then. It appears either no one knows or they just aren't saying... lol